# Select table cell in react bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, html-table, bootstrap-4

```
export class UsersTable extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        info: null
    };
}

 componentWillMount() {
            fetch("http://localhost:8081/milltime/getUsers")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(info => {
            this.setInfo(info);
        });
}

setInfo(info) {
    const state = this.state;
    state['info'] = info;
    this.setState(state);   
}


render() {
         const info = this.state.info;
    if (!this.state.info) {
      return null;  
    } 

    let listItems = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < info['mta:getUsersResponse']['mta:users'].length; i++) {
        listItems.push(
            <tr> 
                <td>{info['mta:getUsersResponse']['mta:users'][i]['mta:UserId']}</td>
                <td>{info['mta:getUsersResponse']['mta:users'][i]['mta:FullName']}</td> 
                <td>{info['mta:getUsersResponse']['mta:users'][i]['mta:CostHour']}</td>

            </tr>);
    }

  return(
 <div className="usersTable">
   <Table striped bordered condensed responsive hover>
     <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Full Name</th>
        <th>Hour cost</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
       <tbody>
        {listItems}
       </tbody>
   </Table>
 </div>
  );
}
   }
```

This is the code I have for a table that get users and displays 3 columns of data. What I am having problems doing is being able to select a table and by selecting that table get the data in that cell and use it to search with the help of the id of the user in the selected cell. Has anyone got a neat solution? I'm using React bootstrap.

Comment: onClick on the <td> (or tr if you mean the row)? https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind your onClick handler when your creating the row.
See comments in code.

https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

```
export class UsersTable extends React.Component {

      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            info: null
        };
    }

     componentWillMount() {
         fetch("http://localhost:8081/milltime/getUsers")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(info => {
                this.setInfo(info);
            });
    }

    setInfo(info) {
        const state = this.state;
        state['info'] = info;
        this.setState(state);   
    }

    onSelectedRow(user, clickEvent){
      //your user object and the click event
      //clickEvent.currentTarget = the cell clicked
    }

    render() {
        const info = this.state.info;
        if (!this.state.info) {
          return null;  
        } 

        let listItems = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < info['mta:getUsersResponse']['mta:users'].length; i++) {
            const user = info['mta:getUsersResponse']['mta:users'][i]; //dryer
            //Bind you onclick handler to the context and you user object (or id if thats what you want)
            listItems.push(
                <tr onClick={this.onSelectedRow.bind(this, user)}> 
                    <td>{user['mta:UserId']}</td>
                    <td>{user['mta:FullName']}</td> 
                    <td>{user['mta:CostHour']}</td>
                </tr>);
        }

      return(
     <div className="usersTable">
       <Table striped bordered condensed responsive hover>
         <thead>
           <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Hour cost</th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
           <tbody>
            {listItems}
           </tbody>
       </Table>
     </div>
      );
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Api requests **should** be handled in `componentDidMount` lifecycle event as described in React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).

Also, your are mutating your state on `setInfo` and this is not a good practice either. You can directly update your state like:

```
setInfo(info) {
  this.setState({
    info: info, 
  })
}
```

or simply using object shorthand

```
setInfo(info) {
  this.setState({
    info,
  })
}
```

Should your api change in the future, you are gonna have problems replacing all the `mta:**` in your code. Why don't you `map` them upon state?

```
this.setState({
  info: {
    users: info['mta:getUsersResponse']['mta:users'].map(user => ({
      id: user['mta:UserId'],
      fullName: user['mta:FullName'],
      costHour: user['mta:CostHour'],
    })) 
  }
})
```

Click handling becomes easier from now, just create a `UserRow` component, send `user` as prop and propagate changes on `onClick`.

```
const UserRow = ({ user, onClick }) => 
   <tr onClick={onClick}> 
     <td>{user.id}</td>
     <td>{user.fullName}</td>
     <td>{user.costHour}</td>
   </tr>
```

Now you can `map` though your state and propagate props to it:

```js
const UserRow = ({ user, onClick }) => 
   <tr onClick={onClick}> 
     <td>{user.id}</td>
     <td>{user.fullName}</td>
     <td>{user.costHour}</td>
   </tr>

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      info: {
        users: [ 
          { id: 0, fullName: 'User 1', costHour: 100 },
          { id: 1, fullName: 'User 2', costHour: 50 },
          { id: 2, fullName: 'User 3', costHour: 150 }
        ]
      }
    }

    this.handleUserClick = this.handleUserClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleUserClick(user) {
    console.log(`user ${user.id} has been clicked`)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="usersTable">
       <table striped bordered condensed responsive hover>
         <thead>
           <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Hour cost</th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
           <tbody>
            {this.state.info.users.map(user =>
              <UserRow
                key={user.id}
                user={user}
                onClick={this.handleUserClick.bind(this, user)}
              />
            )}
           </tbody>
       </table>
     </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```